# receive a broadcast when there is incoming and outgoing data in android

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I am using the following code to receive a broadcast when there is incoming and outgoing data in android but the when I switch wifi off and on to test it I am not receiving the broadcast.

> Android manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.neo.testtrack1" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".IncomingCall"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

> Code:-

```
        public class IncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

        Context c ;

        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            c = context;
            try {
                // TELEPHONY MANAGER class object to register one listner
                TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

                //Create Listner
                MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();



                // Register listener for LISTEN_CALL_STATE
                tmgr.listen(PhoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_ACTIVITY | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Phone Receive Error", " " + e);
            }



        }

        private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

            @Override
            public void onDataActivity(int direction) {
               super.onDataActivity(direction);
                Toast.makeText(c,"Data activity",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String LOG_TAG = "Connection state";
                switch (direction) {

                    case TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_NONE:
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDataActivity: DATA_ACTIVITY_NONE");
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_IN:
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDataActivity: DATA_ACTIVITY_IN");
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_OUT:
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDataActivity: DATA_ACTIVITY_OUT");
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_INOUT:
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDataActivity: DATA_ACTIVITY_INOUT");
                        Toast.makeText(c,"Data connection inout",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case TelephonyManager.DATA_ACTIVITY_DORMANT:
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDataActivity: DATA_ACTIVITY_DORMANT");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onDataActivity: UNKNOWN " + direction);
                        break;
                }



            }

}
}
```